# Problem with Copy and PasteSpecial (changing sheet name )

Tags: excel, vba

The below code copy rows from `sheet "Opened"` (based on condition ) and paste on another `sheet "Closed"` in the same workbook and there is another event code on sheet "Closed" to prevent change name of that sheet.

**Problems:(1)** If I run copy code while `sheet "Opened"` is activated ,I got `Run-time error 1004 That name is already taken.` this error related to `sheet "closed"`. no such error if I run code while sheet "closed is" activated.

```
Sub Copy_PasteSpecial()

Dim StatusColumn As Range
Dim DestRng As Range
Dim Cell As Object

    Set StatusColumn = Sheets("Opened").Range("H3", Sheets("Opened").Cells(Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp))
    
        For Each Cell In StatusColumn
         If Cell.value = "Close" Then
            Set DestRng = Sheets("Closed").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
            DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
          End If 
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

And this code for Prevent Changing Sheet Name:

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If ActiveSheet.name <> "Closed" Then
   ActiveSheet.name = "Closed"
End If
End Sub
```

This link for the real workbook: https://easyupload.io/7ftxik

Comment: DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats , But even I delete this line the second line of PasteSpecial raise the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ActiveSheet` in

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If ActiveSheet.name <> "Closed" Then
        ActiveSheet.name = "Closed"
    End If
End Sub
```

is not the sheet the `SelectionChange` event is in. That would be `Target.Parent`

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Parent.Name <> "Closed" Then
        Target.Parent.Name = "Closed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Waleed_wwm: It's a basic rule on SO to ask one thing in one question. If you have another question, create a new question. Which answer would you accept if now your second problem is answered by someone else?